# Validator retrieve property values from Bean in Spring-boot (Alternative to BeanUtils)

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I want to build a validator between two fields in POJO inside my Spring-Boot app.

I searched an example how to make it and I found this code:

```
Object checkedValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(object, selected);
```

My problem is that I can't use BeanUtils.getProperty(object, selected),

How can I get the property from my bean ?

Comment: Why would you need `BeanUtils`. Just get the properties using the getter and do the validation.

Comment: I am looking to put this on the custom validator I wrote on the class itself. Typically it can be specified on any class filed of similar type and it has do the validation as I specify it to

Comment: Will update the question with a bit more insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to pull specific values, you can simply use the `getDeclaredFiled` from the `Class`. A typical code block for this implementation as per the code you have will look as specified below:

```
Class<?> tempClass = object.getClass();
Field field = tempClass.getDeclaredField(selected);
field.setAccessible(true);
Object checkedValue = field.get(object);
```

If you are referring to pull environment variables, You can use `Environment` from the Spring's core package `package org.springframework.core.env`

If you are using annotations, simple `@Autowire` the `Environment` and you can retrieve the property like you do using BeanUtils. Typical code block would like as specified below

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

String value = environment.getProperty("property_name");
```